# How can I merge two file smartly with unique key?

Tags: shell

I have two files, such like:

File1:

```
A,Content1
B,Content2
C,Content3
```

File2:

```
D,Content4
E,Content5
B,Content6
```

There is the same key in file1 and file2, could I merge two files smartly that the result file is just as:

```
A,Content1
B,Content2
C,Content3
D,Content4
F,Content5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this with a single `sort`:

```
sort -t',' -k1,1 -u file1 file2
```

It sets the field separator to comma, sorts and dedupes on only the first field.

Comment: Note that order matters. If the OP wanted the columns from `file2` to win, the order should be swapped to `-u file2 file1`

Answer (score 0):

If your files aren't too big (which is what I'll assume from your usage of shellscript) :

```
#!/bin/bash
keys=$(cat "$@" | cut -d',' -f1 | sort -u)
for key in $keys
do
  grep -h $key "$@" | head -1
done
```

Basically :

- extract the keys (stuff that is before the first comma)
- find the first occurrence of that key in the files (that's the head -1)

Comment: Just a few tips, use `"$@"` over `$*` to preserve grouping when whitespace is present.  Also, `$(echo $keys)` can be replaced with just `$keys`.